# What's the meaning and the use of "home" and "in" in "thumped home" and "thumped in"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to understand the use of "home" and "in" in this context. How do they work? It's a little confusing "Thump" means strike the ball hard and its object is "the winner". I, therefore, read "thump the winner" as meaning "strike the ball hard the winner" and it doesn't seem to make any sense whatever. Could you elaborate this construction? I also heard a commentator say "blast in an equaliser" that seems the same thing.

> Raheem Sterling thumped **home** the winner to make it 4-3 and secure the Blues' second trophy of the campaign.

> Raheem Sterling sent Stamford Bridge into delirium when he thumped **in** the winner.

> 70min: More chances have come and gone for City!
> Bernd Leno acrobatically tipped over Raheem Sterling's close range header moments earlier.
> And from the corner that followed, the ball was again worked to the substitute, but he bent his effort wide of the far post after **jinking in**.

[Man City vs Chelsea](https://www.mancity.com/news/first-team/match-report/2019/february/chelsea-v-man-city-carabao-cup-final-match-report)

Comment: You should write down these things you hear/see so you can reuse them. Check out this site: https://languagecaster.com/

Answer (score 19):

"Thump" means to hit something hard.

"Thump home" means to hit something hard and to send it to somewhere it belongs. A billiard ball might find "home" in the pocket, a basketball in the hoop, and a soccer ball in the goal. The context is very important to determine what "home" refers to exactly, but generally, it's "where you're trying to put something".

Here, "the winner" refers to the winning goal (the goal that made it 4-3). This can only really be used in a retrospective sense, as you won't generally know which goal was the winning one until the game is over.

Putting it all together, "thump home the winner" in this context means to forcefully kick the winning goal into the net. The meaning is unchanged by swapping "in" for "home", both are referring to the only logical context of what you'd be kicking the ball into - the goal.

Comment: My first thought on seeing the question was of baseball, in which the batter's hit can create an opportunity for a *teammate* to score by reaching home plate.

Answer (score 7):

**This is all football jargon:**

When you kick a football hard (soccer ball), it makes a **thumping sound**. It's a great sound.

So, the sports journalist is using the term to mean kicked the ball very hard.

**thump in** means: thump in[to the goal].

**Thump in the winner** means kick the *winning ball* into the goal.

thump home=to kick it into the goal

**To thump a team can also mean to win a match.**

In that sense (different from the ball), thump means to beat the other team.

In fact, there is an idiom: to give someone a thumping (to beat them or beat them up)

English through football

> This week’s English for football phrase is ‘to thump a team‘. If you
> thump a team it means that one team has beaten another team easily –
> other words that can be used include, thrashed, hammered and
> destroyed. The word thump actually means to strike or beat someone or
> something so we can suppose that if a team is thumped they feel
> battered and bruised, as if they have been beaten up. For example,
> this week Liverpool easily beat Portsmouth in the Premier League – in
> fact the BBC suggested that they thumped the team from the bottom of
> the league. To thump a team.

[English through football](https://languagecaster.com/english-football-phrase-to-thump-a-team-week-32-2009-10/)

There are examples of a football being thumped on Youtube but the sound doesn't come through very well...

Here's the best I could find, looking quickly

[football thump sound](https://www.google.com/search?q=thump%20a%20football%20%2B%20soccer&sca_esv=587728493&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1077US1078&ei=JQxuZaD8CJeIptQPwYq2wAE&ved=0ahUKEwjgoseGp_aCAxUXhIkEHUGFDRgQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=thump%20a%20football%20%2B%20soccer&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGXRodW1wIGEgZm9vdGJhbGwgKyBzb2NjZXIyCBAAGIAEGKIEMggQABiABBiiBDIIEAAYgAQYogRIjh1Q6AVY2xpwAXgAkAEAmAGoAaABwAmqAQMxLjm4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgYQABgWGB7CAgsQABiABBiKBRiGA8ICBRAhGKABwgIFECEYqwLCAggQIRgWGB4YHcICChAhGBYYHhgPGB3iAwQYASBBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:7431bf24,vid:7oeswdvLi5E,st:0)

> **Jinking** Run [from the same site about English through football with a  link above]
>
> When a player dribbles with the ball to beat the opposing defenders.
> **To jink means to move from side to side or to often change direction**.
>
> Example: Lionel Messi beat three players in a jinking run before
> firing past the keeper.
> Example: The winger went on a jinking run
> and then set up the winner with a perfect cross.

So, after jinking in [jinking the ball in, I think] means to move from side to side before trying to get a goal.

Comment: I've never heard anyone use figurative *We **thumped** [the other team]* instead of *We **beat / thrashed / whipped / licked / ...** them* (we won by a significant margin).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I think those British guys know what they are talking about, don't you?// "What we don't want to see is our teams getting thumped. It was embarrassing a wee bit last season in the Champions League." BBC Sport

Comment: Daily Mail: How Mikel Arteta can rally his Arsenal troops after Man City **thumped them** to take control of the title race. Also used as an adjective: thumping win over x

Comment: I obviously don't follow sport enough! But as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=team+thumped%2Cteam+thrashed&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) shows, teams usually ***thrash*** the opposition, not ***thump*** them (especially if you switch to the BrE corpus! :). It's odd that you found so many instances of the American usage on the BBC - but they stopped representing Brits some years ago now.

Comment: ("thumping" has [always been a valid intensifying adjective](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+thumping+great%2Ca+thrashing+great&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=20), but "thrashing" never was)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just spoke to a friend in London who is very involved locally with Leyton Orient and he was surprised that a fellow Englishman did not know the term. The Champions League quote is from a UK person; not any American.

Comment: Also, the two guys who do that site (link in my answer) on football are **both English**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What does "in" mean in this sentence? Raheem Sterling sent Stamford Bridge into delirium when he thumped **in** the winner.

Comment: @Nyambek: [The meaning is unchanged by swapping "in" for "home", both are referring to the only logical context of what you'd be kicking the ball into - the goal.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/344903/126)

Comment: By "did not know the term", you imply I might have had difficulty understanding the cited usage. But as the chart in my second comment shows, even in the AmE corpus, ***thumped*** is less common that ***thrashed*** for what sporting teams do to the opposition. And the latter term is so uncommon in the BrE corpus there's not enough to chart. That evidence strongly suggests *some* Brits are adopting the predominantly American usage. It's not feasible that Brits independently came up with the same substantial shift from figurative ***thrashed*** to ***thumped***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why are you arguing with me when two English pro football commentators define the term? What does it matter what is more common or where it came from? Here, they used thumped. The usage is attested in British football by two experts.

Comment: @Nyambek Why are you **again** asking about thump in? I explained it in my answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, what about this one? What does "in" mean? – Ward's free-kick from deep is curled **in** behind the Fleetwood backline and begging for a touch.

– A geat ball **in** from the left, intended as a cross, goes just wide of the far post

Comment: @Lambie Does *verb + in* always mean the ball goes into the goal? For instance: ...blasts/fires/smashes/slams **in** a strike from outside the box.

Comment: @Nyambek It depends on the verb.  All goals are made from outside the box. You are now expanding the question. I don't much like that use of strike. The player is a striker, yes, but "in a strike" doesn't sound right to me. A ball in from the left means it came in [to a player] from the left side.

Comment: @Nyambek: In those two examples, ***in*** is more like ***inwards** (towards the target / goal).* Where it blends seamlessly with the *completely* figurative "containment metaphor") in, say, [***homing in** on a target*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home%20in%20on). Amusingly, that dictionary definition specifically says it's often used figuratively, with example *Researchers are homing in on the cause of the disease*. But obviously definition *to find and move directly toward (someone or something)* with example *The missile was homing in on its target* is figurative too!

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the word ***in*** is used alone without a verb, does it mean ***inwards*** (*towards the target / goal)*?  – Another lovely United goal. Fred finds Rashford in the middle with a lovely right-to-left diagonal pass. Rashford slips wide left to Fernandes, who chips delicately back into the centre. Rashford eyebrows it towards the bottom right, off the post, and **in**!"

Comment: @FumbleFingers What does "in" mean in this sentence? Marcus Rashford darts into the area, ***hammers in*** a first-time shot from wide on the right of the area, and Lukasz Fabianski makes a really good one-handed save to turn it away.

Comment: @Lambie Well, the word "strike" means a shot, is it uninterchangeable with "shot?" As for "in", sometimes it refers to the ball goes into the goal and sometimes it just refers to ***inwards*** (into the target goal). For instance: Eriksen crossed from the right and Adebayor ***headed in*** from five yards. Here *head *in* suggests  *head **into the goal***, doesn't it? Can we substitute "in" for "home"? *Adebayor headed home from five yards*.

Comment: @Nyambek Now you are telling me by citing another comment? I have more than answered your question(s). I have already told you that "in" generally refers to "in[to] the goal". "in" is not inwards. "headed in" in that article means he made a goal with his head (to head a ball). "head into the goal" means nothing, btw. in=a ball goes in and a ball can also go out.

Comment: Sports journalism is full of jargon, slang, metaphors, allusions, and elaborate synonyms, which make it difficult to follow if you're not familiar with the genre.

Answer (score 5):

This is idiom and quite slangy.

Something's home is the place where it belongs, the place it should be.  So where should the football be?  Answer: in the back of the net!

Saying "The winner" is metonymy (or is it synecdoche?) It refers to the ball, as the agent of scoring a goal.

So Sterling "Thumped home something": he kicked something very hard, to where he wanted it to go.  What did he kick? "the ball, which caused a goal to be scored, which resulted in his side winning the match"

Two points for improving your understanding:

1. Don't try to analyse the words like this.  Understand sentences not words.  Here, it is easy to understand that Raheem scored the winning goal, by kicking the ball hard.  You don't need to think of synecdoche to understand that.
2. Remember that commentators are speaking live, So listen, don't read.  You don't need to be able to translate everything that was said, you are mostly looking to get insight into the match as it happens.

Comment: This is all English football jargon, but it is not slang.

Comment: @Lambie - I wonder if your words will hit home?

Comment: Can I say the sentence without "home"? Raheem Sterling sent Stamford Bridge into delirium when he **thumped the winner**.

Comment: @Nyambek - You _can_, but it means something somewhat different.  That would just mean that he hit "the winner", which could be "the winning ball into the goal" or could be "the player who scored the winning goal" (as in "thumped the winner on the back").  In the right context, it could even mean refer to something like "he took the ball that scored the winning goal and then hit it into the stands".  So to convey the original meaning, you need _something_ that references the goal (like "home", "in").

Comment: @Nyambek Why try and change everything? Thump home is to kick into the goal like I said in my answer. thumped in the winner and thump home the winner are two ways to say: kicked the ball into the goal, the goal which won the match.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically on "jinking in", which I don't think any other current answer adequately explains:

> 70min: More chances have come and gone for City! Bernd Leno
> acrobatically tipped over Raheem Sterling's close range header moments
> earlier. And from the corner that followed, the ball was again worked
> to the substitute, but he bent his effort wide of the far post after
> jinking in.

"The substitute" here refers to Raheem Sterling, you can think of it as [elegant variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation) on the part of the commentator, to avoid saying the name over and over.

"Jinking" has been covered: it refers to moving (usually with the ball) in an unpredictable way, quickly and repeatedly changing direction to confuse the defenders

However, the "in" in "jinking in" has a quite specific meaning: it means **in a direction away from the the wings and towards the 'spine' of the pitch**, an imaginary line from one goal to the other. I just made up 'spine' there, I don't know if there's a more commonly-used word.

So:

> And from the corner that followed, the ball was again worked to the
> substitute, but he bent his effort wide of the far post after jinking
> in.

Reworded:

From the corner, the team made a series of passes which ended with Sterling having the ball. He jinked *from* a position towards the side of the pitch, *to* a more central position; took a shot; but the shot missed.

That *from* ... *to* is what the "in" means.

You could also use "out" to refer to the other direction: from the 'spine' towards the wings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does "in" in these sentences mean the same thing as your explanation above? – Rasford **thunders in** a strike from outside the penalty box that misses the goal.

Soucek **ghosts in** and volleys past the goalkeeper.

Comment: I think those are both using *in* in a different sense - simply, generally towards the target goal

Comment: In *ghost in* and *cut in*, does the **in** mean "run *into the goal*? SOUCEK STRIKES AGAIN!
A GOAL IN FIVE GAMES IN A ROW FROM TOMAS SOUCEK!
Kehrer tees up Cornet, who **cuts in** on his left foot and curls a deep cross to the fat post, where Soucek **ghosts in** and volleys past the goalkeeper!
It's almost a carbon copy of his winner at Burnley on Saturday!
FK TSC 0-1 West Ham United

Comment: "Cuts in" is probably the 'towards the 'spine'' sense I discuss in this answer. "Ghosts in" is probably 'in the general direction of the target goal', but I'd need to have seen the match to be sure...

Comment: Thanks, AakashM. Does "in" mean "toward the spine" in this sentence? –Marcus Rashford darts into the area, **hammers in** a first-time shot from wide on the right of the area, and Lukasz Fabianski makes a really good one-handed save to turn it away. – Tierney **drives in** from the left and wins another corner for the Bhoys as his right-footed shot takes a deflection again

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think the "in" in two examples means towards the spine. Am I right?

Comment: I'd say both are 'goalward', actually. They are **shots** after all. You have to look at the wider context.

Comment: Well, in "hammer **in** a first-time shot", does "in" mean into the goal? The ball goes into the goal.

Comment: *Towards* the goal is where shots go. As it says in your text, the keeper saved it. That's all from me.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the use of "in" here. "Thump in the winner" means strike the ball hard into the goal, but "hammer in a shot" just mean strike the ball hard towards the goal, not into the goal. I think if the ball isn't in the net, the right preposition is "towards". So it would be "Hammer towards a shot". The "in" suggests the ball goes into the net.